# check if coordinates are Double

Tags: mongodb

So I am running into a small error, where some of the coordinates are not Double and are instead Strings.

I am wondering how do I run a query to show me all coordinates that are stored as strings instead of Double?

currently some are stored like this.

```
{"location":{"coordinates":["115.8621","-35.8"],"type":"Point"}}
```

I need them converted to Double  to look like

```
{"location":{"coordinates":[115.8621,-35.8],"type":"Point"}
```

I have since updated the mongoose scheme to be correct

Comment: You can use $type for this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I tried and could not get it to work

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Should be this one:

```
db.collection.find({ "location.coordinates": { $type: ["double", "long", "int", "decimal"] } })

db.collection.find({ "location.coordinates": {$not: { $type: ["double", "long", "int", "decimal"] }} })
```

I assume `long, int, decimal` would be also valid values.